# Create HTML table from 2 lists in python 3

Tags: python, html, html-table

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475123/easiest-way-to-turn-a-list-into-an-html-table-in-python) but the solution is still not working out for me...
I have `2 lists`

```py
list1 = ['src_table', 'error_response_code', 'error_count', 'max_dt']

list2 = ['src_periods_43200', 404, 21, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 26, 21, 10, 7)',
         'src_periods_86400', 404, 19, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 21, 10, 7)']
```

The `list1` carries the `column names` of the `HTML` table.

The second `list2` carries the `table data`.

How do I generate the `HTML table` out of these 2 lists so that the first list is used for `column names` and the second as the `table data` (row-wise)

the result should be:

```html
src_table          |  error_response_code  | error_count  | max_dt                  |
src_periods_43200  |  404                  | 21           | 2020-5-26    21:10:7    |
src_periods_43200  |  404                  | 19           | 2020-5-25    21:10:7    |
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should do it

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

list1 = ['src_table', 'error_response_code', 'error_count', 'max_dt']

list2 = [
    'src_periods_43200', 404, 21, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 26, 21, 10, 7),
    'src_periods_86400', 404, 19, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 21, 10, 7)
]


index_break = len(list1)
if len(list2) % index_break != 0:
    raise Exception('Not enough data.')

staged_list = []
current_list = []

for idx in range(0, len(list2)):
    current_list.append(list2[idx])

    if len(current_list) == index_break:
        staged_list.append(current_list.copy())
        current_list = []

df = pd.DataFrame(data=staged_list, columns=list1)

print(df.to_html())
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for... thanks... do you know how to add a little bit of formatting? @Supun De Silva

Comment: You can pass a list of css classes to `.to_html()` function as an array.

i.e `df.to_html(classes=['my-table-style'])`

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your function for that
Something like:

```py
import datetime

list1 = ['src_table', 'error_response_code', 'error_count', 'max_dt']

list2 = ['src_periods_43200', 404, 21, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 26, 21, 10, 7), 'src_periods_86400', 404, 19, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 21, 10, 7)]

print('<table>')
print('<thead><tr>')
for li in list1:
    print(f'<th>{li}</th>')
print('</tr></thead>')
print('<tbody>')
for i in range(0, int(len(list2)/4)):
    print('<tr>')
    print(f'<td>{list2[4*i+0]}</td>')
    print(f'<td>{list2[4*i+1]}</td>')
    print(f'<td>{list2[4*i+2]}</td>')
    print(f'<td>{list2[4*i+3]}</td>')
    print('</tr>')
print('</tbody>')
print('</table>')
```

Comment: If you don't want to print it, you can make str+= ...., and then send it somewhere